# cPanel service failed to start, error - Can't locate Cpanel/Version/Tiny.pm

Tags: cpanel

I cann't access WHM or cPanel service. I am getting following errors while starting the service.

## systemctl status cpanel.service

Can't locate Cpanel/Version/Tiny.pm in @INC
Failed to start cPanel services
Unit cpanel.service entered failed state
cpanel.service failed

I tried the below but the errors are still there.

```
/scripts/perlinstaller YAML::Tiny
/scripts/perlinstaller Version::Tiny
/scripts/perlinstaller HTTP::Tiny
```

tried upcp but it fails :

/scripts/upcp --force

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this same error a couple of weeks ago and it was due to missing/corrupt data in:

> /usr/local/cpanel/

You can compare the size and files in that directory with another cPanel installation and if you have missing data, sync it from another server running the same version.

If you have a backup, you can also use it for a restore.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, it causes due to missing Cpanel or apache files...
First of all check this folder: `cd /usr/local` then it will show you a list of folders, compare them a working cPanel server. I am sure rather that you will find some folder like Apache or cPanel is missing.
Try to transfer the missing folders and files from the working version through **SFTP** programs such as **FileZilla/WinSCP**  to the unworking version

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, updating it fixes the issue.

I ran the script update it fixed everything for me..

```
/scripts/upcp --force
```